# UILabel text moved

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have a UITextView in which it has a place holder text in it, however, when I tried to type in something to the UITextView it moved my UILabel text to the right a bit. Why is this? I can't seem to figure out how this could happen. Here's a [video](http://www.screenr.com/E3Ds) showing the issue.

I am using SSTextView from Sam Soffle's SSToolkit [here](https://github.com/samsoffes/sstoolkit/blob/master/SSToolkit/SSTextField.m) for the UITextView.
All the other is pretty much standard. Can anyone tell me why is this?

Not sure if it helps, but can it be due to:

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    [self.textCount setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%3d/142", textView.text.length]];
}
```

Comment: if you keep typing letters dose the text on the right keep moving to the right.. or dose it just jump that one time?

Comment: Okay that throws my theory out the window. sorry bout that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 [self.textCount setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%3d/142", textView.text.length]];
```

When you first init your TextField do you have the same formatting?
If you have set in in IB, remove it from there and set it in code with that formatting.

But maybe a simpler solution would be to justify your text to the right and place your TextField accordingly, so you wouldn't event have to deal with the place holder.

Answer (score 0):

Have you log out the frame information of that UILabel to see if it's really moving?
I'm not sure the problem is that the UILabel is moving.
The moving occur when you first modify it's text. This make me think that the problem maybe something else.

How, where and when are set the text property of that UILabel may hold the key to that mystery.

Comment: you mean how that text in UILabel is set?

Comment: What are the parameter you use for displaying text and if the first text that appear is set in the same fashion as the following. But before looking into that; put some NSLog() before and after the moment that it's moving, to see if that option can be dropped of not.